# Exciting standing waves in piston/valve ended pipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, acoustics

Suppose a pipe is connecting a high pressure with a low pressure region. Within this pipe there is a piston/valve that can be opened or closed and a large pressure drop.

As the valve is opened, air is flowing with a velocity *v* through the pipe. My question is: is it possible to create standing waves (sound waves) between the valve and the pressure drop if the valve is opened/closed at certain frequencies?

Suppose the answer is yes, I was trying to calculate the frequencies at which this would happen. But while the pressure drop clearly would be a pressure anti-node, I have no idea what the valve would be (node or anti-node). I don't think the fact that the medium itself is moving is playing a role, since it would affect the waves in opposite ways when travelling in opposite directions, hence cancelling out.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure you can really have a standing wave in the "formal definition" of the term. I believe that standing waves are defined for "steady-state", temporally continuous (in the sense that they are not interrupted) waves. In case you open and close the valve then you create temporally varying boundary conditions which will alter the solution to the wave equation in a temporally continuous way. You may be able to achieve a wave pulse (or pulse train most probably) that will travel back and forth with minimal losses (for ideal case with certain boundary conditions) but this is not (cont.)

Comment: what a standing wave is... Please note that I didn't go on to actually solve the problem/system and my comment is based solely on intuition.

Comment: @ZaellixA Thanks for the interesting take, I will try to work further on the wave pulse!